# Авторизация в микросервисах

Tags: python, django, микросервисы

Существует микросервисная архитектура. В ней есть несколько сервисов,один из них это авторизация.
Каждый сервис работает остраненно.Каждый сервис должен знать что пользователь прошел авторизацию для того чтобы дать ему право делать что то. Ведь я не буду каждый раз,когда с фронта приходит jwt на один из сервисов делать запрос к сервису авторизации.

Авторизация на [django](/questions/tagged/django)

По возможности пример или статью с использованием Python.

Comment: Ну если джанго то у тебя куки у клиента есть и есть ид сеанса в бд. Рассматривал этот вариант? Каким образом клиент с микросервисами общается? Обращается ли он к ним напрямую?

Comment: Дело в том,что сервисы работают даже на разных бд, есть конечно вариант через брокер толкать,но тоже энергозатратно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой подход, что сервис аутентификации/авторизации генерирует `jwt` токен используя приватный ключ, который знает только он. А на каждом клиентском сервисе установлен соответствующий ему публичный ключ. Тогда каждый отдельный микросервис может сам без запроса к сервису аутентификации/авторизации достать из `jwt` токена данные для аутентификации/авторизации.

Comment: Все гениальное - просто, спасиб)